# Click Event For Cross Page PostBack

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have a `Search.aspx` page with **TextBox** and **Button**. The `postback` is to `Results.aspx` which has a GridView.  The Sql query works as I have checked it with QueryDesigner.

In theory, a pseudo-search should be done by typing a value into the text box and clicking the button.  When I enter a value and click, the `Results.aspx` page opens but is blank.

The click event in the `Search.aspx` is nothing more than:

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){}
```

This setup does work in a Web Project, however, will not in a Web Site, which this is.  It would appear that the click event is not working by not submitting the value to the `Results.aspx` page.  I have had no luck finding a click event which will work.  I would appreciate any help.

EDIT:  The sql query is complicated but as I said, it works fine when a value is entered in the Query Designer.  I did add a "namespace" to the .cs as Web Sites, as opposed to Web Projects, normally do not have a namespace.

Search.aspx

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Search.aspx.cs"  Inherits="LinqTest.Search" %>

 <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head runat="server">
<title></title>
 </head>
 <body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Name"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Search" PostBackUrl="~/Results.aspx"  />

</div>
</form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Search.cs

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Web;
 using System.Web.UI;
 using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

 namespace LinqTest
 {
 public partial class Search : System.Web.UI.Page
 {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
}
```

ResultsSearch.aspx

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="ResultsSearch.aspx.cs"   Inherits="RecipeFaire.ResultsSearch" %>

 <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
 <%@ PreviousPageType VirtualPath="~/Search.aspx" %>
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<!-- this is the results of the search done on the search.aspx -->
<div>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="RecipeID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="2">
                    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Width="100px" Height="80px"  ImageUrl='<%# "~/Handler.ashx?RecipeID=" + Eval("RecipeID")%>' />
                </td>
                <td rowspan="2" width="100px">
                    <asp:Rating ID="Rating1" runat="server" align="right" valign="top" CurrentRating='<%# Eval("RatingAVG")%>'
                        MaxRating="5" ReadOnly="true" StarCssClass="ratingStar" WaitingStarCssClass="savedRatingStar"
                        FilledStarCssClass="filledRatingStar" EmptyStarCssClass="emptyRatingStar">
                    </asp:Rating>
                    &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<br></br>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" align="right" Text='<%#  Eval("Count") %>' />&nbsp&nbsp
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="Home" Font-Size="Small" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Bind("RecipeID", "../../Comments.aspx?RecipeId={0}") %>'
                        Text="Reviews" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Bind("RecipeID", "PageLinkDetails.aspx?RecipeId={0}") %>'
                        Text='<%# Eval("RecipeName") %>'></asp:HyperLink>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="width: 500px">
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="DescriptionLabel" valign="top" runat="server"  Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>' />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5" style="color: LightGrey">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Font-Size="1px" Height="1px"   Text='<%# Eval("RecipeID") %>'></asp:Label>
                    <hr style="border-style: dotted" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <LayoutTemplate>
            &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<asp:LinkButton
                runat="server" ID="SortByName" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="RecipeName">Sort By Recipe Name</asp:LinkButton>
            &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="SortByPrice" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="RatingAVG">Sort By Rating</asp:LinkButton>
            <table id="Table1" runat="server">
                <tr id="Tr1" runat="server">
                    <td id="Td1" runat="server">
                        <table id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" border="0" style="">
                            <tr id="Tr2" runat="server" style="">
                                <th id="Th1" runat="server">
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="Tr3" runat="server">
                    <td id="Td2" runat="server" style="" align="center">
                        <asp:DataPager ID="DataPager2" PagedControlID="ListView1" PageSize="8" runat="server">
                            <Fields>
                                <asp:NumericPagerField ButtonCount="8" />
                            </Fields>
                        </asp:DataPager>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </LayoutTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:RecipeUploadConnectionString %>"
        SelectCommand="SELECT pr.RecipeID, pr.CategoryName, pr.CategoryType, pr.RecipeName, pr.Description, COUNT(rr.RecipeID) AS Count, AVG(rr.Rating) AS RatingAVG 
        FROM PostedRecipes AS pr LEFT OUTER JOIN RecipeRatings AS rr ON pr.RecipeID = rr.RecipeID 
        WHERE pr.RecipeName LIKE '%' + @RecipeName + '%' OR pr.CategoryName LIKE '%' + @CategoryName + '%' 
        OR pr.CategoryType LIKE '%' + @CategoryType + '%' OR pr.CuisineOrigin LIKE '%' + @CuisineOrigin + '%' 
        OR pr.CuisineType LIKE '%' + @CuisineType + '%'  GROUP BY pr.RecipeID, pr.RecipeName, pr.CategoryName, pr.CategoryType, pr.CuisineOrigin, pr.CuisineType, pr.Description">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:FormParameter FormField="RecipeName" Name="RecipeName" Type="String"/>
             <asp:FormParameter FormField="CategoryName" Name="CategoryName" Type="String" />
            <asp:FormParameter FormField="CategoryType" Name="CategoryType" Type="String"/>
            <asp:FormParameter FormField="CuisineOrigin" Name="CuisineOrigin" Type="String" />
            <asp:FormParameter FormField="CuisineType" Name="CuisineType" Type="String"/>
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
</div>
</form>
</body>
 </html>
```

ResultsSearch.cs

```
 using System;
 using System.Data;
 using System.Data.SqlClient;
 using System.Configuration;
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Web;
 using System.Web.Security;
 using System.Web.UI;
 using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
 using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
 using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
 using System.IO;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Web.SessionState;


 namespace RecipeFaire
 {

public partial class ResultsSearch : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }
}
}
```

Comment: can you show some code? any errors etc?

Comment: Thanks for your effort. The code is above.  I am not getting any error messages, just a blank page on the target page.  The same result with or without the "namespace".

Comment: Please show the complete markup of your Search.aspx.  There must be some more markup else it will not work as verified OR are you sure you are using only this much of markup in Search.aspx ???

Comment: That is all the markup for Search.aspx. and it works fine in a Web Project.  This is being used in a Web Site. Difference being Project uses "namespace" in code behind, Site does not. The auto-generated at the top of the page for a Project is: Inherits="RecipeFaire.ResultsSearch".  The auto generated for a Site is: Inherits="ResultsSearch".  Since the Project does work, I tried to import the namespace on the .cs and the .aspx (via the inherits) It appears there is some behind the scenes coding by VS.  That coding is what I am missing.

Comment: Is the label text a parameter in the query that populates your listview? Im a little confused on what you are trying to accomplish here.

Comment: You will need to find the control (`Label2`) within the `ListView`.

Comment: That is my problem.  Please see my Edit above.  I have tried everything I know but cannot get the Label recognized, and I am asking for any help/suggestions.  @briskovich, please see my edit above.

Comment: here is how to use findcontrol in a listview. Hope it helps. You bind your list first and then find the label in the row of your list.
http://forums.asp.net/t/1277682.aspx

Comment: @briskovich, thank you but that link is for " the button which submits the form is also inside your listview ItemTemplate". My button is on the Source.aspx, posts to the Target.aspx, which is in the edit above.  What I am trying to do is put "xxx" into a TextBox on the Source and have it post to the Target (which it does) and have a Label or any other (depending on coding) item IN the ListView do a query, retrieve the data, and display it in the ListView. The item I would like to do this is labRecipeName,I get a "not in context" error message - if that label is an item "inside" the ListView.

Comment: So the textbox from source is the search term, you post it to target to run the search and fill results in the listview...but you also want a label on the listview to run ANOTHER query? This seems a bit off.

Comment: @ethorn10, what you said is exactly correct except I don't want to run ANOTHER query. I want to run the query from the source page to the target ONLY. However, if the target .cs, as above, contains an item INSIDE the ListView, labRecipeName, for example, the error is thrown, "not in current context".  If labRecipeName is moved "outside" the ListView but onto the target page, the error message goes away and the search text will appear on the target page, however, since it is now outside of the ListView, the query will not execute.(CHANGE the originally posted .cs from Label1 to labRecipeName)

Answer (score 0):

i am seeing something weird...

in your search.aspx... you have this.

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Search" PostBackUrl="~/Results.aspx"  />
```

However, in your 2nd page listing... you posted this...

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="ResultsSearch.aspx.cs"   Inherits="RecipeFaire.ResultsSearch" %>
```

the PostbackUrl is **Results.aspx** and the other page you posted in **ResultsSearch.aspx**.

Can you check if this is the problem? (i cant post comments yet.)

Comment: Please see my comment above to FlopScientist.  My mistake sending that code to you.  Believe me, I am aware of what you are pointing out and I have corrected that and PostbackURL is not the problem - I have it correct on this end.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely aren't showing us all of your code-behind, but we'll assume you are doing this somewhere:

```
ListView1.DataSource = SqlDataSource1;
ListView1.DataBind();
```

After you've done that, **THEN** you can find the `Label` and set its text (do not do this in the `Page_Load` prior to binding).

```
protected void ListView1_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
  {
    Label recipeName = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("labRecipeName");
    recipeName.Text = Request.QueryString["RecipeName"].ToString()
  }
}
```

To use a querystring value for your `SqlDataSource`, use a `QueryStringParameter`:

```
<SelectParameters>
    <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="RecipeName" QueryStringField="RecipeName" Type="String" />
</SelectParameters>
```

Comment: ethorn10, I appreciate your time. I have given all of the code behind above, in an edit.  I am obviously somewhat lost in trying to do this and I can see where your code above is binding the ListView which I was missing.  If you could clarify based on my code behind above, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: oh well, so much for that.

Comment: It's really difficult to figure out what you've attempted. You say that you got it working as long as the label isn't buried in the ListView...is it not sufficient this way?

Comment: thank you for getting back to me. Please see my recent edit above.  If the label isn't buried in the ListView, the ListView will not execute the query.  In the last edit, I have attempted to explain my problem fully.  I honestly do not know how I can explain the problem I am having any clearer.  I'm not sure how this site really works, but 49 people have viewed this post and you are the only one to really address my concern, and I really do appreciate your effort.  I am amazed that such "computer/coding experts", in the 49, can't address this.  Thanks to you again.

Comment: I wouldn't get discouraged with stackoverflow - this is by far the best place for answers. But honestly, the vast majority of "computer/coding experts" are going to avoid a `SqlDataSource` like the plague.